# Merge case class in a sequence

Tags: scala

I am trying to merge case class in a sequences.
i.e I have the following case class:

```
case class Output(a: String , b: String, c: String, d: Int)

val outputSeq = Seq(
  Output("serviceA","targetA","8000",0),
  Output("serviceA","targetA","8080",1),
  Output("serviceA","targetA","8000",0)
)
```

I would like to achieve the following output:

```
  Map(serviceA -> List(Output(serviceA, targetA, 8080, 0), Output(serviceA, targetA, 8080, 1))
```

following gives me the map but I am stuck how to get rid of duplicates. I know I need to further filter using map but I am a noob in scala FP.

```
outputSeq.groupBy(_.a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `mapValues()` [has been deprecated](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#mapValues%5BW%5D(f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.MapView%5BK,W%5D) (as of Scala 2.13.0) it's recommended that we use the long form.

```
outputSeq.groupBy(_.a)
         .map{case (k,vs) => k -> vs.distinct}
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning why it's deprecated (or linking to the docs saying so at least).

Answer (score 2):

Silly me. I could do.

```
outputSeq.distinct.groupBy(_.a)
```

I am loving scala. :)